# How can I span a Remote Desktop session in Windows 7 across two of three monitors?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is there a way to have Windows 7 span Remote Desktop across two of my three monitors?

My local computer is Windows 7 Professional and the remote computer is Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

True multiple monitor support in Windows RDP is only functional if the target machine of the session is running Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise.

EDIT: Apparently, from exchange in the comments, this actually doesn't work.  You can either work in single monitor mode, or multiple monitor mode, but if you do the latter you have to use ALL of your monitors, you're not able to selectively disable them.  Anybody know a workaround?

Comment: The target is Win7 Enterprise.  So what else do I need to do?

Comment: If you're running the newest version of RDP, you should be able to simply check the option in question in the Display configuration in the RDP connection dialog options.  I forget exactly how it's worded but it should be obvious.  I have no firsthand experience with this but it came up with a customer of ours...I don't recall having to do anything else.  Let me know if for some reason you don't have that option and I can look into it.

Comment: Addendum: see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: I have a option for "Use all my monitors for the remote session" but that will use all 3

Comment: Once you do that, can't you disable the third once the session is up?  I could have sworn you could do that, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Disable by going to the Display Properties on the Remote machine?  If thats what you mean it says you can't change the display settings.

Comment: Oh, yeesh, then I guess I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something other than RDP, there are solutions which will work for all versons of windows for free.  Logmein.com will span all monitors.  You must have a logmein.com client installed on the remote computer, however.  I've been using it for years, and it works great.

Comment: I'll have to check if I'm allowed to run that.